# Access a serialized array in php?

Tags: php, ajax

I pass an array to php from ajax using:

```
data: {
    imageData: ctx.imageData,
    formData: $("#content-add-form").serializeArray()
},
```

Ignore imageData, im only concerned with formData. This outputs:

```
array(2) { [0]=> array(2) { ["name"]=> string(5) "title" ["value"]=> string(8) "my title" } [1]=> array(2) { ["name"]=> string(4) "date" ["value"]=> string(10) "16-09-2013" }}
```

But how can I access each part of the array using keys?

Eg.

```
$_POST['title']
```

Comment: When in doubt `var_dump($_REQUEST);`. jquery's serializeArray() uses json. So you'll probably be using `json_decode()`

Comment: Json decode does not work

Answer (score 2, accepted):

How about `$_POST['formData']['name']` ?

**Edit:**

It seems like your data is serialized like this:

`$_POST['formData']` <- Array with all fields.

`$_POST['formData'][0]` <- Array with field name and value of first form element.

`$_POST['formData'][0]['name']` <- The name of the first form element.

`$_POST['formData'][0]['value']` <- The value of the first form element.

I guess you're looking for the last one.

**Edit 2:**

Maybe this is what you're looking for:

```
data: {
    imageData: ctx.imageData,
    formData: $("#content-add-form").serialize()
},
```

http://api.jquery.com/serialize/

**Edit 3:**

You're right. This must be it:

```
// Get the form data.
var data = ("#content-add-form").serialize();

// Add additional data.
data.imageData = ctx.imageData;

data: data,
```

Comment: Your updated answer won't work either. I need to access each item by key not number.

Comment: .serialize() just sends a string, I cant access array elements with this